# How do I preserve data in Django templates on a drop-down menu?

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am trying to preserve form data on a registration template on a Django project. I am using ginger statements such as {{ old_data.[data] }}. I have no problem doing it with regular text input (like this):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="zip_code" id="zip_code" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Zip" value="{{ old_data.zip_code }}">
</div>
```

And with textarea (like so):

```
<textarea type="area" name="area" id="area" class="form-control 
textarea" rows="3" placeholder="Please tell us briefly in what part 
of town you live and how far you are willing to travel for 
rehearsals and performances. i.e., 'I live in the Heights but I'm 
willing to drive anywhere within the loop.'">{{ old_data.area }} 
</textarea>
```

But I cannot figure out how to do it with a drop-down menu. Here is my current code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="primary_instrument" id="primary_instrument" placeholder="Primary instrument" value="{{ old_data.primary_instrument }}">
<option selected disabled>Primary instrument</option>
    {% for instrument in instruments %}
        <option value='{{ instrument.id }}'>{{ instrument }}</option
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Please help!

Comment: Did you actually miss a closing bracket for your `</option`?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over it, and check for every element if the value corresponds to the value of that option, if that is the case, you add a `selected` attribute:

```
<select class="form-control" name="primary_instrument" id="primary_instrument" placeholder="Primary instrument">
<option selected disabled>Primary instrument</option>
    {% for instrument in instruments %}
        <option value='{{ instrument.id }}' {% if instrument.id == old_data.primary_instrument %}selected{% endif %}>{{ instrument }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Note the `{% if instrument.id == old_data.primary_instrument %}selected{% endif %}`. We thus check if the value is the same, and if so, we add the `selected` attribute to the `<option>` tag.

Comment: Hmm... This seems closer, but I don't think it is quite there. Did you not mean to surround `{% in instrument.id == old_data.primary_instrument %}selected{% endif %}` with any other syntax?

Comment: @garreth: I don't understand why we need other syntax? We have access to the `instrument` option we have to render, as well as the `old_data.primary_instrument`, hence we can simply check if these are the same.